# Вывод контента в зависимости от страны

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте, стоит такая задача.. в контактах для посетителей страны России показывать один блок контактов, для посетителей с Украины другой, для всех остальных два блока одновременно

Напал на просторах интернета на 
http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/

И написал такой вот код:

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Test GeoIP</title>
  <script src="http://js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .geoip { display: none; border: 1px solid #036; padding: 10px; margin: 10px; }
    p { font-size: 0.8em; text-align: center; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
    var id, country = geoip2.country();
    switch (country) {
      case 'RU':
         id =  'country-ru';
         break;
      case 'UA':
         id =  'country-ua';
         break;
      default:
         id =  'country-other';
    }
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
  <div class="geoip" id="country-ru">
    <h1>Блок для пользователей из России</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="geoip" id="country-ua">
    <h1>Блок для пользователей из Украины</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="geoip" id="country-other">
    <h1>Блок для пользователей из неопределенной страны</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Но вот что-то никак не получается полноценно выполнить.. получается я не могу вытащить сам "iso_code"...

А может кто-то предложит и какой-то другой вариант решения?

Answer (score 0):

так а почему вы пишете

```
switch (country) {
```

если должны писать

```
switch (country.iso_code) {
```

?

Comment: пробовал, идет ошибка "Cannot read property 'iso_code' of undefined"..
я вот теперь думаю мб это фишка фри версии..

Comment: Ну значит у вас функция не работает - возвращает undefined а не объект country
Все дело в том, что этот скрипт надо подключать в body, а не в head - перенесите <script src="http://js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> в конец перед </body> и всё заработает

Comment: жаль.. но что-то никаких изменений, попробую наверное какой-то другой вариант/сервис

Comment: и что это за ; после src... ? первые шаги? книжку прочитали какую-то надеюсь? ))
Вы вообще в консоль смотрите что происходит при загрузке? ошибки скриптов,загрузки и прочее?

Comment: еще проблема вероятно есть в этом - onload="init();"... пытаетесь использовать данные документа перед тем, как он готов. 
лучше подключите jquery и вызов делайте из $(document).ready() - https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

просто проверьте, Ukraine - uk. 
http://www.localeplanet.com/icu/uk-UA/
ISO 639

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
function init() {
    geoip2.country(function(result) {
        var id;
        switch (result.country.iso_code) {
        case 'RU':
           id =  'country-ru';
           break;
        case 'UA':
           id =  'country-ua';
           break;
        default:
           id =  'country-other';
      }
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    }, function(error) {
      // вывод ошибок
    });    
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш вариант заработал) 
а я уже реализовал через yandex.geolocation, там получилось попроще) но кажется там загрузка подольше, проведу тесты и выберу вариант